# Datasets or dumps for log4j log files?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, dataset, log4j2

I was working on building a log classifier for different kinds of logs - server access logs, linux syslogs etc, and log4j was one of those categories.

I've been looking for some real life examples of log4j log files to be able to train my model (I could manually generate them, but they might not be representative of actual log files). Any open source project or public datasets/dumps that might be relevant?